# jQuery draggable inside iframe: how to move the parent scroll bar

Tags: jquery, iframe, draggable

I have a problem with the draggable configuration inside an iframe.

My draggable objects live inside an iframe and need to interact with the vertical scroll bar of the page that defines the iframe.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trigger-from-iframe-to-parent-window

Comment: It's not what I was searching for. The problem is, as I said, how to move the parent vertical scroll bar when I drag an element inside the iframe (defined with option scrolling="no") that exits the window.